# C - types not matching

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on my homework and I don't want someone to do my homework I just want to know what problem with my code is.

Error:

```
C:\Users\Cojik\Desktop\Codeblocks files\zadaca2_zadatak1\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\Cojik\Desktop\Codeblocks files\zadaca2_zadatak1\main.c|28|error: invalid operands to binary > (have 'float *' and 'float')|
C:\Users\Cojik\Desktop\Codeblocks files\zadaca2_zadatak1\main.c|29|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'float' from type 'float *'|
C:\Users\Cojik\Desktop\Codeblocks files\zadaca2_zadatak1\main.c|39|error: invalid operands to binary  (have 'float *' and 'float')|
C:\Users\Cojik\Desktop\Codeblocks files\zadaca2_zadatak1\main.c|63|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'float' from type 'float *'|
||=== Build failed: 8 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i ,j;
    float arr[1000], max1=-999999999999999.0, max4=-999999999999999.0, min2=999999999999999.0, min3=999999999999999.0;
    printf("Enter the number n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n<3||n>30)
        printf("Worng entry!");
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("Enter the elements of %d. row: ", i+1);
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(i>j && i<n-1-j)
                {
                    if(arr[i]>max1)
                        max1=arr[i];
                }
                if(j>i && j<n-1-i)
                {
                    if(arr[i]<min2)
                        min2=arr[i];
                }
                if(i>j && j>n-1-i)
                {
                    if(arr[i]<min3)
                        min3=arr[i];
                }
                if(j>i && i>n-1-j)
                {
                    if(arr[i]>max4)
                        max4=arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
        if(max1==max4 && min2==min3)
        {
            printf("Array is simetrical!\n");
            printf("Elements: o1 = %.3f, o2 = %.3f, o3 = %.3f, o4 = %.3f", max1, min2, min3, max4);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Array is not simetrical!\n");
            printf("Elements: o1 = %.3f, o2 = %.3f, o3 = %.3f, o4 = %.3f", max1, min2, min3, max4);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Does my array need to be two-dimensional?  My code is giving the wrong answers if it is two-dimensional and this error appears if it is one-dimensional, which is not intended.

Comment: please post the code. It seems you are using the pointers in a wrong way in your code.

Comment: `float` and `float*` is a different type.

Comment: From all error messages I think it's pretty obvious that he is trying to use a pointer to float as a float, or not?.

Comment: It's great that you posted the error messages. Unfortunately, they're not of much use without the code.

Comment: You should usually post the code, but I can assume from the error messages that in lines 28 and 39 you compare between a float* (which is either a pointer to a float but in this case you mentioned arrays) and a float (which is probably a regular variable or a spot in your array), just make sure that if it's an array you use in lines 28 and 39 you should always use square brackets'[]' and when it's lines 29 and 63 the problem is probably assigning a float variable the value of a pointer (which is probably your array), again, make sure to use square brackets to mention WHERE in that array.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your compiler is getting mixed up. Anyway, the initializers of max1 .. max4 are too large for a float. Use a double.

I also note that you do `if(max1==max4 && min2==min3)`, however, it is bad practice to absolutely compare two floating point values. You should compare them equal within epsilon, the machine precision:

```
#define epsilon 0.0000000001; //(I don't say this value is correct; just an example)
#define ABS(a) (a<0?-a:a)

if(ABS(max1-max4)<epsilon && ABS(min2-min3)<epsilon)
```

Comment: @Aleksandar Misich, thanks for your edit. I noticed a  bug in my example and updated my solution.